# Yammer embedded stop working in classic SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, yammer

I was wondering if anyone has faced this issue. The embedded code is given by Microsoft and as following

```
<div id='embedded-my-feed' class='col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 yammer-home-feed pz-cell-container'>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://c64.assets-yammer.com/assets/platform_embed.js'></script> 
<script type='text/javascript'> yam.connect.embedFeed({ container: '#embedded-my-feed', network: 'network.co.uk', feedType: 'Home Feed', config: { use_sso: true, header: false, footer: false }});</script></div>
```

It was working before but now has stopped working. I want to display home feed and it doesn't have feed id. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested to emb yammer feed like this in classic page and it works as expected:

```
<div id="embedded-my-feed" style="height:400px;width:500px;"></div> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://c64.assets-yammer.com/assets/platform_embed.js"></script>
<script 'type="text/javascript"> 
yam.connect.embedFeed({  
              container: '#embedded-my-feed',
              network: 'microsoft.com',
              config: { header: false, footer: false},
              feedType: 'Home Feed'
    });
</script>
```

[image]

Please check error with Browser Developer Tool and you can try to clear browser cache and then resign in to see if it works.

Comment: thanks Jerry, it was problem with our tenant . Have raised Microsoft ticket